# Автоматическое подключение модулей в gulp-mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, юнит-тесты, mocha

Я использую *[gulp-mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-mocha)* для тестирования. Мне также нужно задействовать другие библиотеки, вроде *chai*, во всех тестах. Я мог бы написать что-то вроде этого внутри каждого теста:

```
const {assert} = require('chai');
```

Но я бы хотел автоматизировать подключение подобных библиотек, т.к. тот же *chai* все равно будет использоваться в 99% моих тестов. Т.е. грубо говоря, я не хочу копировать *require* всех нужных библиотек в каждый файл с тестами. Нужно, чтобы библиотеки (а лучше определенные их части, вроде *assert* у *chai*) сразу же были доступны как глобальные переменные.

Я знаю, что у *mocha* есть такие параметры, как *global(s)* и *require*. Однако, судя по [данному вопросу](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-mocha/issues/89), *gulp-mocha* не поддерживает *require*, а как работает *global*, я без понятия. Из [оф. документации](https://mochajs.org/#-global-variable-name) толком ничего про *global* не понял.

Мой таск с тестами на данный момент:

```
const test = () => gulp.src(files.src.js, {read: false})
    .pipe(mocha({
        globals: {chai},
        reporter: 'mocha-multi',
        reporterOptions: {
            spec: '-',
            tap: files.reports.jsTest
        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31290131/11195930 .

*Gulp-mocha* на самом деле поддерживает *require*, как и любые другие параметры *mocha*. В свою очередь *require* должен передавать параметры не через *module.exports*, а просто в виде глобальных переменных. Причем переменные нужно задавать именно как свойства объекта *global*. В итоге написал небольшой скрипт, который и передаю в *require*:

```
// Вспомогательная функция, позволяет как можно более кратко экспортировать библиотеки
function exportLibs(libs) {
    for (let libName in libs) {
        const lib = require(libName);

        if (libs[libName] === true) {
            global[libName] = lib;
            break;
        }

        for (let name of libs[libName])
            global[name] = lib[name];
    }
}

// Здесь указываются все нужные библиотеки
exportLibs({

    chai: ['assert']

});
```